# Cronjob to kill process if mysql server is down

Tags: linux, apache, shell, cron, high-availability

I have 2 web servers (Zion_HQ,Zion_Cloud) loadbalanced (HAPROXY) with two mysql servers(Cyvorex_db_HQ, Cyvorex_db_Cloud). I would like to setup a cronjob (on webservers) to test if the sql server is available for a given webserver, if not shutdown the apache process, so that loadbalancer would failover connections to the healthy host.

[image]

Here is a corn jobs that I've been working on.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if curl -1IsS -k  https://10.20.20.60 | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null

    then echo "The HTTPS server on 10.20.20.60 is up!" > /dev/null

    else echo "The HTTPS server on 10.20.20.60 is down!"

    fi
```

How would I shutdown the apache2 process with this script and bring it back online. I would like to run this as a cron job every 5 seconds. I don't mind looping processes or invoking multiple processes.
I'm new to shell scripting, any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I don't get your setup. If both front-end servers are talking to *both* back-end servers (via the diagonal lines), why do you need failover on the front-end layer? After all, **both** servers are talking to the DB server which could fail.

Comment: @l0b0 Only one front end server is active at a time. it is Failover not Loadbalance.I'm not concerned about front-end its connectivity between backend-web and db servers that i'm worried about. Because HAProxy(TCP mode not http) would gladly present one of the web servers even if the db server connection is severed.

Comment: I've got this script running but unfortunately it is not killing httpd process when mysql is down
`#!/bin/bash
if curl -1IsS -k  https://10.20.20.60 | grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" > /dev/null

        then echo "The HTTPS server on server is up!" > /dev/null

else
/usr/bin/systemctl stop httpd.service


fi
`